# Different filename for global composer.json

Tags: composer-php

Just started working with composer and having some issues installing apps globally. I am using this on a linux machine running ElementaryOS. When I run `composer global require "laravel/installer"` it gives me an error that it cannot find `./composer.json` file in the current directory. First why would I need something that I am installing globally?

So if I need one, could I just create in my home directory a .composer.json and when I do a global install can I just point to that file?

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out. Instead of putting the `.composer.json` in the home directory, I just put it in the .composer directory. Then I just named the file `composer.json` as it will not pollute my home dir anymore